# How to solve java.sql.BatchUpdateException: number not valid

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to insert record in database an error stating:

> Could not execute JDBC batch update

error is displaying along with

> "java.sql.BatchUpdateException: number not valid" error message.

I am using Oracle and JSP as a technologies. It all shows error files with respect to weblogic server and net.sf.hibernate files.

Please tell the possibility of resolving this issue.

[image: Please refer to the error from the server]

[image: Please refer to the error from the server]

[image: Please refer to the error from the server]

[image: Please refer to the error from the server]

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct exact error message? we don't know your database nor the SQL query for insertion. Not your Hibernate settings...so how can anybody help here?

Comment: The only message Google returns and is somewhat similar to yours is `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number` - is that what you get?

Comment: No. I got the above message when I tries to submit the form which reflects the database

Comment: Strange that your the first visiting this error message...but anyways, I don't see how people can help you without any further information but just the error messages which has exactly one hit at Google -> your question here.

Comment: Actualy I m working on remote system. If you want I can give you the screen shots of the error

Comment: you could at least add the screenshot here - maybe others know the issue.

Comment: by the way, I'd guess that the input in the form might be invalid, e.g. not a number at some point although expected by the DB? Do you validate the data before insertion?

Comment: Yes. We do the validation

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with Oracle APEX. Please remove the tag if that is true.

Comment: Given that the invalid number error appears to be in Spanish, are you sure your numbers are appropriately formatted?

Comment: I'm still thinking that the number in your form is not a proper number that can be processed by the database, that's why the update query fails.

Comment: So what can be the possible solution @AKSW

Comment: Even if when I am selecting the checkbox. It gives me error message that "Please select the checkbox"